# How to switch window screen in list format like ubuntu studio in Ubuntu 17.06?

Tags: lubuntu

Lately I was using Ubuntu studio in which there was this feature to switch screen in list format( Alt + Tab) , how I can achieve the same in Ubuntu? As while switching it shows the icon too ?

Comment: Explicit state what you want. Do you want a switch feature with windows view ? Have you tried Super+Tab ?

Comment: Every thing is fine. I do not want to change the key bindings and all. What I like to do is , alt+tab feature is in horizontal , I want them in vertical and without any icons.